# What kind of plants are these

Tags: identification, houseplants

I got these plants at a nursery and I’m trying to figure out what they are called there are 3 of them in this bowl.

[image]

Comment: Hi Celena, for identification questions it works better for one plant per question. Which one are you most interested in?

Comment: The bright green one I really have no clue what it is as well at the dark red and green plant that kinda looks like poison ivy

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you had attached close-up shots of individual plant pictures. But based on the given picture, it looks like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN4p8.png) plants are Polka-Dot plants. They come in many colourful combinations (pink, dark red, half-white etc.,)